# Flink windows performance hit

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

**What is a reasonably expected performance hit while using processing windows in Flink?**
I have a [flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/) job which is able to process about 25K records without using a [window](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/windows.html).

As soon as I add a time window to the job, performance drops to about 13K records even without processing its output. Using different time periods (1s, 10s, 120s) seems to not matter as they all produce similar results.

What I want to achieve is simply get the most recent record having the same Id within each second.
Currently the window looks more or less like this:

```
stream.keyBy(Record::getId)
.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(1)))
.reduce((rec1, rec2) -> rec2);
```

Is a ~50% performance drop a reasonable "price" for using windows?

Comment: What state backend are you using? Do you have checkpointing enabled?

Comment: Did the windowless job have a keyBy? The network shuffle and corresponding serialization/deserialization that come from keyBy are expensive.

Comment: @gcandal state backend: MemoryStateBacked. checkpointing: disabled

Comment: @DavidAnderson no, windowless job did not have a keyBy. The steps before the window are: a source, split, filter and map. No big magic. Everything on a single machine with paralelism=1.